# Async in JScript

Tags: c#, .net, jscript, jscript.net, cs-script

I've recently noticed that the library I'm using to compile and use C# files like scripts in my applications (CSScript) can compile VB and JScript as well. One of my applications makes use of await/async (C# 5) though, does this exist in JScript? I can't seem to find anything using Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Async/await is syntactic sugar added to C# and VB.NET. You can still work with `System.Threading.Tasks` in JScript, but these keywords are a language-specific feature.

You can confirm this by looking through the JScript spec:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/72bd815a(v=vs.100).aspx